# Is there a difference in weight between "without flaw" and "flawless"

Tags: word-usage

Is there a difference between the weight or impact between **flawless** and **without flaws**? It seems to me that **flawless** is rather close to **perfect**, and **without flaws** would be just **mistakeless**.

Am I wrong in this assumption?

Comment: Just a heads-up. You received two closevotes so far and the reason seems to be **answers to this question will tend to be entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise**. Now, can you try to edit your post to give us some of your research, context and examples where you feel "flawless" is close to "perfect" and "without flaws" would be just "mistakeless"?

Comment: "Without flaw" sounds more hoity-toity than "flawless".

Comment: @Hot Licks True, but the hoitiest and toitiest want flawless in their best friends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Flawless** is a technical term to grade the clarity of a diamond, as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_clarity)

> Clarity is one of the four Cs of diamond grading, the others being
>   carat, color, and cut
>
> Diamonds with higher clarity grades are more valued, with the
>   exceedingly rare Flawless graded diamond fetching the highest price......
>
> Flawless category (FL) diamonds have no inclusions or blemishes
>   visible under 10x magnification.

**To answer your question:**  To people who know jewelry or people who want the most value in the most portable package, "*flawless*" means something specific, agreed upon around the world, and which can be verified.  To such people "*without flaws*", applied to diamonds, can mean anything or nothing, and is a red flag.

For others, whether **flawless** or **without flaws** sounds more weighty would be a matter of taste and opinion.